# Can I record 2 Audio-Technica ATR3350 lav mics split into a zoom recorder on different tracks?

Tags: audio-recording, recording, lavalier, podcasts

Podcast setup:

- Zoom H4N PRO
- 2 Audio-Technica ATR3350 Lav Mics
- 3.5 mm Stereo Jack Splitter

I wish to be able to record each mic separately, in case I need to edit out a cough or unwanted noise from one of the mics? Is this possible with this setup? Could one mic go into the mono left and the other mic in the mono right? Is this intuitive in the instructions of the H4N recorder?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to make this work with a couple of 1/8" female to 1/4" male adapters.

Plug a lav mic into the adapter, then the adapter into one of the inputs on the bottom of the Zoom. Press and make sure inputs 1 and 2 are lit up red and record!

However, I believe the Zoom can only record interleaved files from those inputs. The mics would still be separate and editable, the file would just need to be split into two mono files before hand, which pretty much any DAW can do.